The id returns null each time
I am trying to change the information of the material and the way I've tried to do it is there is a list of all materials and within the div of the particular method I have put a change material button that takes you to a different page where there is a form where you can add the new data.
And that form will invoke the edit method. The problem is that when the method is invoked it get an error because the id is null. So somewhere between the second view page and the controller class the id is lost and I don't know how to go about it, what I am missing.
I have tried to get the material.Id and put it in asp and so form will show specifically for that material.
This is the view class where the form is
<form id="editForm" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Merde"  method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id"  />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label">Titel</label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label">Beskrivning</label>
        <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Color" class="control-label">Färg</label>
        <input asp-for="Color" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Color" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Pattern" class="control-label">Mönster</label>
        <input asp-for="Pattern" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Pattern" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MaterialType" class="control-label">Materialtyp</label>
        <select asp-for="MaterialType" class="form-control">
            @foreach (var materialType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MaterialType)))
            {
                <option value="@materialType">@materialType</option>
            }
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="MaterialType" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="saveButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="spara">
        <a asp-action="AdddMaterials" class="btn btn-secondary">Avbryt</a>
    </div>
</form>

This is the method:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, EditMaterialViewModel model)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model.Id);
    //if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
        var material = _context.Materials.Find(id);
    //if (material == null)
    //{
    //    return NotFound();
    //}
        material.Id = model.Id;
        material.Title = model.Title;
        material.Description = model.Description;
        material.Color = model.Color;
        material.Pattern = model.Pattern;
        material.MaterialType = model.MaterialType;

        _context.Update(material);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Ändring av material lyckades!";

    var createMaterial = new CreateMaterial();

    /*var materials*/
    createMaterial.MaterialsList = _context.Materials.ToList();
    createMaterial.Materials = new Materials();

    // ViewBag.Materials = materials;
    return View("AdddMaterials", createMaterial);
}

And this is where I try to get the id from:
@foreach (var material in @Model.MaterialsList)
{
if (material.Deleted == false)  // Check if material is not deleted
{
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">Material: @material.Title</h5>
           <p class="card-text">Beskrivning: @material.Description</p>
           <p class="card-text">Färg: @material.Color</p>
           <p class="card-text">Mönster: @(material.Pattern ?? "Inget mönster angivet")</p>
           <p class="card-text">Material Typ: @material.MaterialType</p>

           <!-- Delete Button -->
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@material.Id" />
           <button onclick="openPopup(@material.Id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
           <button class="btn btn-primary"><a class="linkToTheFuckItEverythingIsGoingWrong" asp-area="" asp-controller="Merde" asp-action="EditMaterialViewModel" asp-route-id="@material.Id">Ändra material(@material.Id)</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
}


So, in your Edit method, what does Console.WriteLine(model.Id); show?  If it doesn't have the ID, does the view that is posting to that method have the ID as a hidden field on the form?  If not, where on the form is the ID?

check the functions id parameter instead of the model.Id parameter. One of the two should have the id. Currently you are duplicating it. Check your Url as well you might need to add an explicit route before the endpoint definition if you are using segments.

" So somewhere between the second view page and the controller class the id is lost" What's the relationship between second  view page and edit page ? Could tou share more code about second view page ? How it pass the id or excute the edit action ?

Can you try specifying the "name" attribute to the hidden input field?

Do you need to add in "asp-route-id = Model.Id"  to the form - so that your passing the id through

A friend helped me solve it and it was because I didn't have a relationship between the second view page and the controller so I needed this 'public IActionResult EditMaterialViewModel(int id){var createMaterial = new CreateMaterial();
createMaterial.Materials = new Materials();
createMaterial.Materials.Id = id;
return View(createMaterial);}' that made connections so the id could be resevied

A friend helped me solve it and it was because I didn't have a relationship between the second view page and the controller so I needed this
public IActionResult EditMaterialViewModel(int id)
{
    var createMaterial = new CreateMaterial(); 
    createMaterial.Materials = new Materials(); 
    createMaterial.Materials.Id = id; 
    return View(createMaterial);
}

that made connections so the id could be resevied
